# Did R2-D2 ever meet Yoda prior to Yoda's exile on Dagobah?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, yoda, r2-d2

Is there a specific proof in the canon (of any kind) showing that R2-D2 had met/seen/been aware of existence of Master Yoda at any time between the siege of Naboo and Yoda going into Exile on Dagobah?

The most plausible possibility I can think of is on Senator Organa's ship at the end of *Revenge of the Sith*, right before they split the Skywalker twins. But I don't remember if it was explicitly shown that R2 was in a position to see Yoda (as opposed to, say, being in the engineering areas of the ship).

NOTE: This question is very closely related to this one: [Why does R2-D2 try to electrocute Yoda?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3253/why-does-r2-d2-try-to-electrocute-yoda) - but that question's answers seem to have merely glossed over **whether** R2-D2 saw Yoda before.

> That said, I'm going to continue my answer with the assumption that R2 HAS seen Yoda, but I have no evidence for this. (from Jeff's winning answer)

This question itself was prompted by Chad's comment to my answer to [Was Yoda fully sane on Dagobah?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6343/was-yoda-fully-sane-on-dagobah/6345#6345)

Comment: After episode 3, its possible that R2's memory was wiped out by Emperor's system..

Comment: Don't forget, the make-up of the Jedi High Council (including biographies and holograms) is likely a matter of public record.  Given his association with so many Jedi, R2 would most likely access that information at some point, especially if Anakin were whining about how unfairly they treated him.

Comment: R2's like the great Honey Badger... he just didn't give a ****

Answer (score 47, accepted):

R2D2, C3PO, Yoda, Bail Organa, and Obi-Wan are all present at the birth of Luke and Leia, so R2 has met Yoda (and this was NOT retconned out in the blu-ray -- I just finished watching it 5 minutes ago).

Comment: Not to mention R2 traveled with Anakin and Obi-Wan on their missions not only in the movie but in the cartoon.  R2 and Yoda have a few poignant moments in the clone wars where Yoda seems to confide in the little astromech.

Answer (score 23):

## Yes

In the last episodes of season 6 of *Star Wars: The Clone Wars*, R2-D2 actually visits Dagobah *with* Yoda during Yoda's trials to learn the art of maintaining one's individuality in the cosmic force after death.

[image: Yoda stands in the foreground, looking offscreen to the right. Behind him on the left is his Jedi starfighter with R2-D2 visible in the astromech socket.]

So in answer to this question, yes, R2-D2 and Yoda have met before.

<sub>Why doesn't he remember Yoda or Dagobah?  As mentioned in the other answers, only C-3PO's memory banks were wiped.</sub>

Comment: So he did remember!

Comment: Actually, the final *3* episodes of Season 6 ;)

Answer (score 8):

It's entirely possible that R2 didn't know who Yoda was when he met him on Dagobah.  We know that C-3PO's memory was wiped at least once, probably more, which is why he didn't know Obi-Wan when he met him on Tatooine. It is not inconceivable that at one or more points across the years in between that R2 also had his memory wiped.

The one I've always found more unexplainable is that Obi-Wan doesn't seem to recognize C-3PO and R2-D2 when he saves Luke from the Tuskans.

Comment: Always chalked that up to him being a huge liar.

Comment: C3PO is custom-built, so yeah, I agree. R2D2 is just another R2 unit as far as Obi-Wan is concerned.

Comment: Good points.  I always assumed he knew far more than he ever let on.  And what he did share was always skewed to his "certain point of view"

Comment: R2's memory was never wiped. Captain Antillies was told only to wipe 3P0's memory, not R2s. Additionally, had R2 been wiped, there would have been no way for Luke to see how Padme died in the Killik books.

Comment: I haven't read any of those books.  Interesting.  I'll have to check them out.  R2 is the only one in the movies that seems to know what he's doing most of the time.

Comment: Obi Wan's comment in Ep IV is, IIRC, "I don't seem to remember owning a droid." It's not that he doesn't know R2. It's that Luke's just stated that R2 claims R2 belongs to Obi Wan Kenobi.

Comment: Ah, good point.  I'd forgotten that line.  I haven't watched them in a while.

Comment: In that scene where Kenobi say "I don't recall owning a droid" - he gives R2 a knowing sideways glance

Comment: I'm sorry, this answer is wrong. __R2-D2 _never_ had a memory wipe__. see [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/84628/why-did-lucas-choose-to-keep-memory-of-r2-d2) and [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/55619/why-was-c3pos-memory-wiped-but-not-r2d2s/84657#84657).

Comment: Even if Obi-Wan *did* remember owning a droid, it would still be technically accurate to say that he doesn't *seem* to remember owning a droid, given that he just gave Luke the impression that he doesn't remember. Old Ben is sneaky like that.

Comment: Well there is that deleted scene from ROTJ (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SDWhoo36-tE) where Yoda reveals to Luke that he wouldn't let Obi-Wan tell him the truth. So Obi-Wan was basically hiding the truth because Yoda told him to.

Comment: There is lots of evidence that R2 met Yoda. I watched season 6 of Clone Wars myself and R2 and Yoda went on a flight together.

Comment: @Firestryke If you look at the dates, you'll see my answer was long before Clone Wars Season 6 aired.

Comment: Good point, I did not notice.