# What is Yoda's full name?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

What is Jedi Master Yoda's full name?

I will accept an answer from any Star Wars book, movie, or TV show (canon, Legends, etc).

Comment: Bob. Bob Yoda the first.

Comment: @Adamant Verrry funny. :) I suppose he must've had a longer version of his name though. At least when he was born. Maybe Yoda is a name given to him as a Jedi that's totally different than his birth name, like a Sith? That would explain it being just one word. Unless his first name just happened to be "Master" by coincidence.

Comment: Yoda Greene, it is.

Comment: According to Weird Al, it's Yo-Yo-Yo-Yo-Yoda

Comment: Well, I hope this doesn't spoil any revelations in future movies, but it's Snoke.  Yoda Snoke.

Comment: I thought it's pretty obvious his name is Yoda Schwartz.

Comment: I guess that every character that doesn't have a full name are named "Solo" for some reason...

Comment: "I suppose he must've had a longer version of his name though.", Hack-R you might gain some perspective from "[Falsehoods programmers believe about names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)" which is simply about human names (leaving out space alien names :). Someone very dear to me was bestowed a mononym at birth (no surname/familial name), and has a whole set of skills for dealing with corporate and government bureaucracies (and interpersonally) who simply refuse to expect or understand that such people exist. :)

Comment: Da my first name is, and Yo my surname must be.

Comment: His last name is M'right.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

"Yoda" is the only name he has been given in any published media. If he has a longer name, it has never been revealed.

### Interesting aside

It's interesting to note that, in the original treatment for *Empire Strikes Back*, Lucas envisioned Yoda's full name as "Minch Yoda"; this has been circulating for a while, but was electronically confirmed on the old [StarWars.com](http://web.archive.org/web/20110911123202/http://www.starwars.com/databank/character/yoda/index.html)<sup>1</sup>:

> In the early story development of Yoda, the initial descriptions varied from a large alien being to a tiny one. The diminutive direction ultimately won out, and *Empire*'s concept artists developed illustrations of gnome-like and elfin creatures. In the story treatment, Yoda's full name was Minch Yoda, and in the first draft, he was known only as Minch.

However Leland Chee, the Keeper of the Holocron and official manager of *Star Wars* continuity, revealed in a 2007 Q&A on the StarWars.com forums that this is *not* Yoda's canonical name; unfortunately the forums have been taken down (and not accessibly via the Wayback machine), but this particular thread was [archived by a fan](http://www.tm-travolta.net/archives/forums.sw.com/message.jspa%3FmessageID=16225670.html) (bold is my emphasis, italic is from the thread):

> *What's the canon status of the story '[Heart of Darkness](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Heart_of_Darkness)?*'
>
> Yoda never went to Dagobah prior to *ROTS*, so that part is non-continuty. The original story of Yoda confronting Bpfasshi Dark Jedi is from *Heir to the Empire* which had the confrontation taking place during the Clone Wars. And **Minch is not part of Yoda's name**.

As with al things prior to the Great Disneyfication, it's unclear whether this is still true in the new Canon. At the very least, it has not been contradicted.

---

<sup>1</sup> Link courtesy of the Wayback machine

Comment: I agree that is an interesting aside. Gotta love the Wayback machine. Since you can't really prove a negative (at no fault of your own) I won't mark this as the answer until some time goes by. +1 tho.

Comment: "Yoda never went to Dagobah prior to ROTS" [Um, yes he did](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/53154/54827) </retcon> :)

Comment: 6 weeks later I ran into the answer. After Yoda died Luke used his credit card to order a wall calendar on "It's a Trap" and it was revealed that Yoda's last name is Parseghian.http://familyguy.wikia.com/wiki/Yoda  Not sure that it's canon though.

Answer (score 6):

#### Within canon, there is nothing to lead one to believe he has any name other than simply "Yoda".

However, as the annotated screenplays explain, he was originally envisioned to have a slightly different name: *Minch Yoda*. From the notes for *Empire*:

> At that point Yoda did not have a name and was referred to as "The Critter."  **In the story treatment the little creature is named Minch Yoda.** In the first draft Yoda is referred to only as Minch. In his introductory scene Luke asks the creature if he knows of the Jedi Knights, and Minch says he used to serve them.

The name "Minch" has never made it into any canon material in reference to Yoda ([a separate character was later created with that name](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Minch)).

Comment: "The Critter" LOL. So Yoda is a last name. Interesting. I wonder where they got Minch from. Or Yoda for that matter.

Comment: The term "Yoda" (or the more phonetically correct "Yodha") means "Warrior" in Hindi. I always assumed that was the inspiration.

Answer (score -3):

Yoda actually was supposed to have a longer name. His name would have been "minch yoda".

Comment: Based on what? You mean the writer(s)/creator(s) wanted a longer name for him, but decided not to? Can you reference this?

Comment: True, but could you provide a reference?