# When does R2-D2 try to electrocute Yoda?

Tags: star-wars, the-empire-strikes-back, yoda, r2-d2

The question [Why does R2-D2 try to electrocute Yoda?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3253/why-does-r2-d2-try-to-electrocute-yoda) presuposses that such an attempt at electrocution occurred, something that I don't recall ever even happening in *The Empire Strikes Back* in the first place. ***When*** exactly does R2 try to attack or shock Yoda?

Comment: I'm ***convinced*** that I remember R2-D2 shocking Yoda during the fight over the lamp. False memory syndrome, perhaps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### He doesn't.

Or at least he doesn't in the film.

Here's a complete [transcript](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-The-Empire-Strikes-Back.html) of the scene from *Empire*:

"With the aid of a walking stick, the tiny stranger moves over to one of 
the cases of supplies.  He begins to rummage around.

Artoo moves to the edge of the case - standing almost eye level to the 
creature who is carelessly handling the supplies - and squeaks his 
disapproval.

Their tiny visitor pick up the container of food Luke was eating from 
and takes a bite.

```
            LUKE
    Put that down.  Hey!  That's my 
    dinner!
```

The creature spits out the bite he has taken.  He makes a face.

```
            CREATURE
    How you get so big, eating food 
    of this kind?
```

He flips the container in Luke's direction and reaches into one of 
Luke's supply cases.

```
            LUKE
    Listen, friend, we didn't mean to 
    land in that puddle, and if we 
    could get our ship out, we would, 
    but we can't, so why don't you just...

            CREATURE
        (teasing)
    Aww, cannot get your ship out?
```

The creature spots something of interest in Luke's case.  Luke loses 
patience and grabs the case away.  The creature retains his prize - a 
tiny power lamp - and examines it with delight.

```
            LUKE
    Hey, you could have broken this.
    Don't do that.  Ohhh... you're 
    making a mess.  Hey, give me that!

            CREATURE
        (retreating with 
         the lamp)
    Mine!  Or I will help you not.
```

Clutching its treasure, the creature backs away from Luke, drawing 
closer to Artoo.  As Luke and the creature argue, one of Artoo's little 
arms slowly moves out toward the power lamp, completely unnoticed by 
the creature.

```
            LUKE
    I don't want your help.  I want 
    my lamp back.  I'll need it to 
    get out of this slimy mudhole.

            CREATURE
    Mudhole?  Slimy?  My home this is.
```

Artoo grabs hold of the lamp and the two little figures are immediately 
engaged in a tug-of-war over it.

Artoo beeps a few angry, "Give me thats."

```
            CREATURE
    Ah, ah, ah!

            LUKE
    Oh, Artoo, let him have it!

            CREATURE
    Mine!  Mine!

            LUKE
    Artoo!

            CREATURE
    Mine!
```

The creature lets go with one hand and pokes Artoo lightly with one 
finger.  Artoo reacts with a startled squeal, and lets go.

```
            CREATURE
    Mine!

            LUKE
        (fed up)
    Now will you move along, little 
    fella?  We're got a lot of work 
    to do.

            CREATURE
    No!  No, no!  Stay and help you, 
    I will.
        (laughs)
    Find your friend, hmm?

            LUKE
    I'm not looking for a friend. 
    I'm looking for a Jedi Master.

            CREATURE
    Oohhh.  Jedi Master.  Yoda.  You 
    seek Yoda.

            LUKE
    You know him?

            CREATURE
    Mmm.  Take you to him, I will.
        (laughs)
    Yes, yes.  But now, we must eat.
    Come.  Good food.  Come.
```

With that, the creature scurries out of the clearing, laughing merrily.
Luke stares after him.  All he sees is the faint light from the small 
power lamp moving through the fog.  Luke makes his decision and starts 
after the creature.

```
            CREATURE
        (in the distance)
    Come, come.
```

Artoo, very upset, whistles a blue streak of protest.

```
            LUKE
    Stay here and watch after the 
    camp, Artoo."
```

No electrocution occurs. Perhaps that asker was conflating this scene with the one where R2 himself is shocked, later in the film.

Comment: Mandella Effect in full force....